# Chart sourcedata multiple ranges stopped working

Tags: excel, vba

I have code in VBA that is dynamically setting the sourcedata for two charts. This code has been working with ten users for the last five years. Until today, when someone tried to run it on a Windows 10 machine and got Application Error 1004 when it hit the second setsourcedata - first one worked fine.

The difference between the two is that the second one is specifying two ranges not one - anyone have any idea why this has suddenly stopped working?

```
with xlApp.Workbooks(1)
.Charts("Patients").SetSourceData Source:=.Sheets("Patient Numbers").Range("A" & TopRow - 1 & ":C" & CurRow - 1), PlotBy:=xlColumns
.Charts("Financial").SetSourceData Source:=.Sheets("Financial Monthly").Range("A" & TopRow - 1 & ":A" & CurRow - 1 & ",H" & TopRow - 1 & ":H" & CurRow - 1), PlotBy:=xlColumns
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Office 64 bit - I think that is probably what broke it.

Have fixed it using Union instead

```
with xlApp.Workbooks(1)
   .Charts("Patients").SetSourceData Source:=.Sheets("Patient Numbers").Range("A" & TopRow - 1 & ":C" & CurRow - 1), PlotBy:=xlColumns
   .Charts("Financial").SetSourceData Source:=Union(.Sheets("Financial Monthly").Range("A" & TopRow - 1 & ":A" & CurRow - 1 & "),.Sheets("Financial Monthly").RangeH" & TopRow - 1 & ":H" & CurRow - 1)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
end with
```